# Consider the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Then which of the following quotients is an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Which of the following quotient rings is an integral domain:

1. $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$
2. $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+5x+6)$
3. $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^3-2)$
4. $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^7+1)$

Now we know that $R/(a)$ is an ID iff $(a)$ is a prime ideal. Here $x^2+5x+6=(x+3)(x+2)$ so $(x^2+5x+6)$ cannot be prime ideal, hence option $2$ is wrong. But I am confused with rest of the options. All the polynomials are primitive. Does this observation provides any help? How should I proceed? Please help.

Comment: Hint: for a UFD $R$ and a polynomial $f(x) \in R[x]$, the quotient $R[x]/(f(x))$ is an integral domain if and only if $f(x)$ is irreducible over $R[x]$. A polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is irreducible if and only if it has degree $1$ or has degree $2$ with nonreal roots.

Comment: So $\mathbb{R}$ is an UFD right? @EthanAlwaise

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{R}$ is a field hence a UFD. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, it is also a PID, so prime ideals are maximal. Therefore $\mathbb{R}[x]/(p(x))$ is actually a field if $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is irreducible. Furthermore, one can show that if $p(x)$ has degree $2$, then $\mathbb{R}[x]/(p(x))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Got it .. thanks

Comment: **Please** do not add «[SOLVED]» to titles. Add an answer with the answer and then accept it; that is the procedure in this site to mark answered questions. I have reverted the question to its previous state.